# How can i format the HTML contents of mail in iphone ?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, mfmailcomposer

I am using MFMailComposer for mailing.I just convert the contents of URL in a string and use that string to send  mail . But the problem is that  HTML file contains button link image  and when i mail it gives two blank icon with the HTML page.How can i remove that icons before the mail is send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not necessary to convert URL content to string. Simply pass `HTML` in `MFMailComposer`.

But even if you want to detect the **TAGs** in content of URL then simply parse the whole HTML of URL and check for button(input) tag. and you can check for completed button tag also.  Simply ignore the statements between starting and ending point of tags and create another HTML content.